# Equivalence of categories of open sets and sheaves.

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathscr{O}(X),\mathscr{O}(Y)$ be the categories of open sets of two topological spaces $X,Y$. To me it's clear that if we have an equivalence of categories between these two this will induce an equivalence of categories (via composition) between the associated presheaf categories.

What happens when we restrict the equivalence of presheaf categories to sheaves? Will composition always respect the sheaf axioms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You could do a low-level check of this by verifying by hand that it does, but a higher level observation works. What the sheaves are on these categories/sites is entirely defined by the structure of $\mathscr O(X),\mathscr O(Y)$ as categories/posets, because in this case a covering (in the 'site'-sense) is the same thing as a covering (in the 'topological space'-sense). Namely, a set of subobjects of an object cover this object if their union -- that is to say, join -- is that object.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting confused because I was working with the traditional notion of covering and that is no good for this sort of reasonings!